# Using R to make Amazon MWS API calls

Tags: r, amazon-web-services, amazon-mws

I'm using R to make a call to the Amazon MWS API and get the following error:

> The request signature we calculated does not match the signature you
>   provided. Check your AWS Secret Access Key and signing method. Consult
>   the service documentation for details.

This [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8251632/amazon-product-api-with-r) helped me a lot with the Product Advertising API.  However, I cannot seem to make it work on the MWS side.

Here is my code:

```
library(digest)
library(RCurl)

base.html.string <- "https://mws.amazonservices.com/Products/2011-10-01?"

SellerID <- 'A2UZXXXXXXXXXX'
MWSAuthToken <- 'ATVPXXXXXXXXX'
MarketplaceID <- 'ATVPXXXXXXXXX'
AWSAccessKeyId <- 'AKIAXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX'
AWSsecretkey <- 'XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX' 
ActionType <- 'GetMyPriceForASIN'
version.request = '2011-10-01'
ASINList.ASIN.1 <- 'B00XXXXXXX'

pb.txt <- Sys.time()

pb.date <- as.POSIXct(pb.txt, tz = Sys.timezone)

Timestamp = strtrim(format(pb.date, tz = "GMT", usetz = FALSE, "%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%SZ"), 24)

str = paste('POST\nmws.amazonservices.com\n/Products/2011-10-01\n',
            'ASINList.ASIN.1=', ASINList.ASIN.1,
            '&AWSAccessKeyId=', AWSAccessKeyId,
            '&Action=', ActionType,
            '&MWSAuthToken=', MWSAuthToken,
            '&MarketplaceId=', MarketplaceID,
            '&SellerId=', SellerID,
            '&SignatureMethod=HmacSHA256',
            '&SignatureVersion=2',
            '&Timestamp=', gsub('%2E','.',gsub('%2D', '-', curlEscape(Timestamp))),
            '&Version=', version.request,
            sep = '')

## signature test
Signature = curlEscape(base64(hmac(enc2utf8(AWSsecretkey), enc2utf8(str), algo = 'sha256', serialize = FALSE,  raw = TRUE)))


AmazonURL <- paste(base.html.string,
                   'ASINList.ASIN.1=', ASINList.ASIN.1,
                   '&AWSAccessKeyId=', AWSAccessKeyId,
                   '&Action=', ActionType,
                   '&MWSAuthToken=', MWSAuthToken,
                   '&MarketplaceId=', MarketplaceID,
                   '&SellerId=', SellerID,
                   '&SignatureMethod=HmacSHA256',
                   '&SignatureVersion=2',
                   '&Timestamp=', Timestamp,
                   '&Version=', version.request,
                   '&Signature=', Signature,
                   sep = '')

AmazonResult <- getURL(AmazonURL)
```

I'm using the Amazon MWS Scratchpad and made sure my string to sign matches.

My secret key does contain +'s, but I thought encoding would fix that.

Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

I figured out my problem after reading this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34777296/amazon-mws-error-signaturedoesnotmatch-python?rq=1).  I took Amazon's examples literally and used a POST instead of GET.  I also had tweaked unnecessarily with my time stamp calculation, which I fixed as well.  Hope this helps someone down the road.

Comment: Hi, can you explain your approach in more detail? I get the "request timestamp too far in the future" error with your code (POST changed to GET)