# MWS API Signature does not match R

Tags: r, amazon-web-services, http, post, amazon-mws

I am trying to get data from Amazon MWS API using GetMatchingProductForId operation.
When I use Amazon MWS Scratchpad it works perfectly fine.

I am now trying to replicate the urls that are sent in the HTTP POST request but I get a Signature error message.
I need to understand how the url request should be structured.

Below is the detail of the request in Amazon MWS Scratchpad, I ANONYMIZED private identifiers but that is the only thing I changed:

HTTP POST

```
POST /Products/2011-10-01?AWSAccessKeyId=ANONYMIZED
&Action=GetMatchingProductForId
&SellerId=ANONYMIZED
&SignatureVersion=2
&Timestamp=2018-09-28T05%3A45%3A43Z
&Version=2011-10-01
&Signature=ANONYMIZED
&SignatureMethod=HmacSHA256
&MarketplaceId=A13V1IB3VIYZZH
&IdType=EAN
&IdList.Id.1=9781933988665 HTTP/1.1
Host: mws.amazonservices.fr
x-amazon-user-agent: AmazonJavascriptScratchpad/1.0 (Language=Javascript)
Content-Type: text/xml
```

String to Sign

```
POST
mws.amazonservices.fr
/Products/2011-10-01
AWSAccessKeyId=ANONYMIZED&Action=GetMatchingProductForId&IdList.Id.1=9781933988665&IdType=EAN&MarketplaceId=A13V1IB3VIYZZH&SellerId=ANONYMIZED&SignatureMethod=HmacSHA256&SignatureVersion=2&Timestamp=2018-09-28T05%3A45%3A43Z&Version=2011-10-01
```

=======

Now my question is, (and let's imagine my signature was created correctly), from the HTTP POST, what should the request look like ?
Here is my attempt:

```
https://mws.amazonservices.fr/Products/2011-10-01?AWSAccessKeyId=ANONYMIZED&Action=GetMatchingProductForId&SellerId=ANONYMIZED&SignatureVersion=2&Timestamp=2018-09-28T05%3A52%3A33Z&Version=2011-10-01&Signature=ANONYMIZED&SignatureMethod=HmacSHA256&MarketplaceId=A13V1IB3VIYZZH&IdType=EAN&IdList.Id.1=9781933988665
```

But what about '\n' escape characters that are in the scratchpad ? and what about `'HTTP/1.1'` at the end, should I include that also ?

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

I don't have an MWS account so I can't test the following, but this is one way you can do it:

```
# set this to your python2 binary; you'll need to do
#   pip2 install boto
# from a command-line before using this code
Sys.setenv("RETICULATE_PYTHON"="/usr/bin/python2.7") 

library(reticulate)

boto_mws_connection <- import("boto.mws.connection")

con <- boto_mws_connection$MWSConnection(
  aws_access_key_id = ACCESS_KEY
  aws_secret_access_key = AWS_SECRET
  Merchant = MERCHANT_ID
)

con$get_matching_product_for_id(
  MarketplaceId = "A13V1IB3VIYZZH",
  IdType = "EAN",
  IdList = c("9781933988665")
)
```

Answer (score 0):

The `HTTP/1.1` is usually created by your http client library. I am not familiar with `R`, but I googled and it seems there is a [CURL package for R](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/curl/index.html). CURL is the standard http library for a lot of languages including PHP. My PHP code to send an XML feed through curl looks like this:

```
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_URL, 'https://mws.amazonservices.fr/Products/2011-10-01?.....your data and signature here...');
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER,1);
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $xmlcontent);
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array(
    "Content-Type: text/xml",
    "Content-MD5: ".base64_encode(md5($xmlcontent,true)),
    "x-amazon-user-agent: TestScript/0.01")
);
$result = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);
```

By looking at [this](https://github.com/jeroen/curl#readme), it seems to me this should be easily translatable to the R interface for CURL.

Comment: but you do not add '\n' characters ? Because in the example url there are escape characters. So my url looks more like this: `"https://mws.amazonservices.fr\n/Products/2011-10-01\nAWSAccessKeyId=..." ` this is not correct?

Comment: The `\n` escape characters you seem to have somewhere are `newline`s. While they *should be* part of the string to sign (as visible in your post it has 4 lines) those *should not* be part of your URL.

Comment: Yes, that's what I did. I think the problem might come from the creation of the signature:             `Signature = curlEscape(base64(hmac(enc2utf8(AWSsecretkey), enc2utf8(string_to_sign), algo = 'sha256', serialize = FALSE,  raw = TRUE)))`   I am not sure `curlEscape` does the work here because the output signature does not look similar to what is in the scratchpad.

Comment: i don't see why any part of the base64 code would *need* to be escaped to be sent over HTTP. I'm pretty sure, the AWSsecretkey should not be transcoded into UTF8 or anything else, after all it is 7bit ASCII. I also don't see why string_to_sign should.

Comment: I followed the script found on this post: [Using R to make Amazon MWS API calls](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36895422/using-r-to-make-amazon-mws-api-calls)

Comment: That post is a bad reference to follow. While his "String to sign" matches with Scratchpad, his signature doesn't. His weird escaping probably is part of why it doesn't.

Comment: In the Scratchpad they write in the request: `"POST /Products/..."` How am I supposed to translate that in the URL, as I should not let any space in the URL.

Comment: The keyword `POST` is *not* part of the URL, just like the `HTTP/1.1` isn't either. Please research a bit more into how HTTP works (especially how headers work) That is way beyond the scope of this SO question